# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION by Java when installing MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab

This is the full error message returned by Java Run Time environment when I tried to install MATLAB:

```
   # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
   #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000776108c5, pid=5616, tid=7436

   # JRE version: 6.0_17-b04
   # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 )
   # Problematic frame:
   # C  [ntdll.dll+0x508c5]

    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

    Current thread (0x0000000000843000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=7436,        stack(0x0000000000030000,0x0000000000130000)]

     siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffffffffff


OS: Windows Vista Build 6000 

CPU:total 2 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 4092272k(1915924k free), swap 8182680k(3737764k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.3-b01) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_17-b04), built on Oct 11 2009 00:46:08 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0

time: Fri Nov 07 20:46:28 2014
elapsed time: 5 seconds
```

How can I fix this problem?

I couldn't install MATLAB due to this problem.